# AngularJS http.get html listing always last image

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to bring a product image to another table with the product number

But, Products are listed while images are always the last item in the array

[Click for screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDqwL.png)

My Angular Controller:

```js
.controller('anasayfaCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams','$http',
function ($scope, $stateParams,$http) {
 $scope.urunler=[];
 $scope.urunGetir=function(){
  $http.get("http://www.elli2.com/mobil/urunler").then(function(response){
   $scope.urunler=response.data;
   
  })
 }
$scope.data=[];
   $scope.gorsel=function(id){
   $scope.data =$http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://www.elli2.com/mobil/urunGorsel/'+id
   }).success(function(response){
  return "url/"+response.urun_gorsel;
   });  
console.log($scope.data);
 }
}])
```

My HTML:

```html
<div ng-init="urunGetir()" >  
      <ion-item ng-repeat="urun in urunler" class="item-thumbnail-left positive" id="anasayfa-list-item5" href-inappbrowser="/urundetay">
        <img ng-src="{{ urunGorsel }}" ng-init="gorsel(urun.urun_id)">
        <h2positive>{{ urun.urun_adi }} 
          <p style="white-space:normal; font-weight: bold;">Fiyat: <span style="color:blue">{{ urun.urun_fiyati }} </span></p>
          <ion-option-button class="button-positive"></ion-option-button>
        </h2positive>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
```

I'm waiting for your help

Comment: ng-src ={{urunGorsel}}??? where is urunGorsel?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to assign the http response to a variable inside `ng-init`

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="urun in urunler" class="item-thumbnail-left positive" id="anasayfa-list-item5" href-inappbrowser="/urundetay">
        <img ng-src="{{ urun.urunGorsel }}" ng-init="urun.urunGorsel = gorsel(urun.urun_id)">
        <h2positive>{{ urun.urun_adi }} 
          <p style="white-space:normal; font-weight: bold;">Fiyat: <span style="color:blue">{{ urun.urun_fiyati }} </span></p>
          <ion-option-button class="button-positive"></ion-option-button>
        </h2positive>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `$scope` property names mismatch (`urunGorsel` instead of `data`), the problem in your code is that you are making multiple requests but store in only one variable. Furthermore, you only store the *promise* instead of its result. You should have something like:

```
$scope.data = [];
$scope.gorsel = function (id) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://www.elli2.com/mobil/urunGorsel/'+id
    }).success(function (response) {
        $scope.data[id] = "url/"+response.urun_gorsel; // Store each image
});
```

And then, in your HTML:

```
<img ng-src="{{ urun.data[urun_id] }}" ng-init="gorsel(urun.urun_id)">
```

Of course, you may need to cache your results and such, but this could help you move on.

Answer (score 0):

```
function anasayfaCtrl($scope, $http) { // home controller
  $scope.urunler = []; // products

  function handleError(res) {
    console.log(res.data);
  }

  $scope.urunGetir = function() { // get products
    return $http.get('http://www.elli2.com/mobil/urunler').then(function(res) {
      return res.data;
    }, handleError);
  };

  $scope.gorselGetir = function(urun_id) { // get image ?
    return $http.get('http://www.elli2.com/mobil/urunGorsel/' + urun_id).then(function(res) {
      return res.data;
    }, handleError);
  };

  // initialize products
  $scope.urunGetir().then(function(urunler) { // init get products
    $scope.urunler = urunler;

    // store products image url in $scope.urunler[x].gorsel_url;

    // initialize each products image url
    $scope.urunler.forEach(function(urun) {
      // urun -> product ?
      $scope.gorselGetir(urun.urun_id).then(function(gorsel) {
        urun.gorsel_url = 'http://www.elli2.com/img_gorsel_/urunler/' + gorsel.urun_gorsel;
      });
    });
  });
}
```

```
<div ng-controller="anasayfaCtrl">  
  <ion-item ng-repeat="urun in urunler" class="item-thumbnail-left positive" id="anasayfa-list-item5" href-inappbrowser="/urundetay">
    <img ng-src="{{ urun.gorsel_url }}">
    <h2positive>{{ urun.urun_adi }} 
      <p style="white-space:normal; font-weight: bold;">Fiyat: <span style="color:blue">{{ urun.urun_fiyati }} </span></p>
      <ion-option-button class="button-positive"></ion-option-button>
    </h2positive>
  </ion-item>
</div>
```